# Find the circle center point that is tangential on 2 other circles that has at least one intersection?

Tags: trigonometry, circles

Given circle A and circle B (we got their center points, radiuses and 1 relevant point where they intersect)

[image]

we want to draw a circle C with a given radius in a way that it is tangential with the other two circles (there are up to 4 possible locations). How to get the possible centerpoints?

[image]

Comment: Use an inversion with center equal to the intersection points of the two circles. The circles transform in two lines...

Comment: @dan_fulea But the condition on circle C of a given radius doesn't easily transform/invert, so I don't see how that's helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** What is the distance between the centers?

To find (say) $O_3$ (which is internally tangent to both $A$ and $B$), what is $|KO_3|$ and $|O_3M|$?
With that info, determine the possible locations of $O_3$.
Note that there are 2 possible locations. (Why?)

Comment: you mean to use (xA-x)^2+(yA-y)^2=(rA-r)^2
 and (x−xB)^2+(y−yB)^2=(rB-r)^2 and solve this two quadratic equations? Is there another way in order to avoid quadratic equations?

Comment: @Mat Depends on what your goal is (IE Missing context). EG If you just want to reproduce this in a graphing software, you can just draw the circles and find the point of intersection. Or, you can solve the general system, and report $(x, y)$ in terms of those values. Or, you have 3 sides of a triangle, so can apply sine rule and cosine rule to determine more information and figure things out from there.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** two circles are tangent at a point $P$ means that $P$ is on the line connecting the two centers.

What does that mean? For example, $M, O_3, N$ are on the same line. Given the radii $R$ and $r$ of the two initial circles, the radius $x$ for the small circle, and the distance $d$ between the original centers, the triangle formed by the three centers has sides $d, R\pm x, r\pm x$. That's a fully determinate problem.